How to connect ceramic resonator to OSC_IN/OSC_OUT pins of CH32V203 MCU?
I want to connect 8MHz ceramic resonator (Murata CSTCE8M00G55-R0) to WCH CH32V203K8T6 MCU to use it as an external clock source. MCU has OSC_IN and OSC_OUT pins that are suitable for connecting crystal oscillator or ceramic resonator (according to the datasheet). I believe that these pins act more or less the same as OSC_IN and OSC_OUT pins of other MCUs like STM.
The connection scheme is provided by the datasheet for crystal oscillator only:

At the same time, ceramic resonator has input, ground and output terminals:

Please excuse me for the dumb question, but should I:

a) Connect OSC_IN to resonator output and OSC_OUT to resonator input OR
b) Connect OSC_IN to resonator input and OSC_OUT to resonator output?


It usually/normally doesn't matter but I found another datasheet (same series, CERALOCK, but may not cover the particular part you have which appears to be obsolete BTW) and the manufacturer suggests connecting the IN pin of the resonator to the OSC_IN of the MCU:

In the alternative part datasheet the following test/measurement circuit is given:

As you can see, the IN pin of the oscillator goes to the input of the inverter of the Pierce oscillator which is commonly found in the MCUs.
So if you worry then just do the same.
But you may also want to check if the resonator's load capacitance (33 pF) is suitable for the MCU. In some MCU datasheets, there are suggestions of load capacitance vs crystal frequency. Check the datasheet for details.

Thanks for the explanation. I examined these schemes but didn't get that the similar scheme as the test scheme may be inside MCU. About the load capacitance, MCU datasheet recommends 20 pF, but doesn't state maximum value. Does it mean that the only way to check whether 30 pF works on not is to test?

@Yury The load capacitance affects the oscillator frequency accuracy so having the load capacitance higher/lower than the MCU mfg recommendation will shift the oscillator frequency. A few pF of difference usually does not harm (i.e. the shift is not that important) but if your application involves high-speed communication (e.g. 1Mbaud CAN) then you may want to follow the mfg advice.

@RohatKılıç It's usually the resonator that needs the rated load capacitance to work with the rated frequency. The MCUs can work with a range of capacitance within limits. And the speed of communication does not matter - if your bit rate is 0.5% off due to ceramic resonator, all speeds are off. It's just what the required precision is, and if you need better than 0.5%, you would not use a ceramic resonator to begin with, and the built-in caps in the resonator have 20% tolerance so their effect is minimal compared to ceramic resonator tolerance.

Usually ceramic resonators don't have separate input and output pins as they are symmetric like crystals are.
If you are worried, connect the MCU input to resonator input, and resonator output to MCU output.
It is unlikely to make any difference. But it appears some resonators are sensitive to the connections.
Murata catalogs show no "polarity" for many other ceramic resonators, but you don't link to any page you quoted the pin names so I can't verify.
Edit: fixed the datasheet terminology where resonator input terminal must connect to oscillator input.

Thanks for the information. I didn't know that resonators are often symmetric. The one that I would like to use is https://t.ly/p0INR (Murata CSTCE8M00G55-R0). It is obsolete, but Murata has newer similar resonator https://t.ly/n06Z5 (Murata CSTNE8M00G550000R0).

The newer resonator data sheet says the in/out terminals are interchangeable, but then the initial tolerance goes up, from 0.5% to 0.6%.

Thank you for the citation from the newer datasheet. I managed to find it, and it really makes things more clear.
